# Uncaught TypeError: Object function has no method

Tags: javascript

The idea is to implement the calculateSurface method from Shape on the inherited class Rectangle, and calculate the surface with the parameters passed on the Rectangle class.

```
function Shape (w,h){
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.calculateSurface = function (){
        return this.w*this.h;
    };
}

function Rectangle (w,h){
    Shape.apply(this, arguments);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.calcSurface = function(){
        return Shape.calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);
    };
}

Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rec = new Rectangle(4,4);

console.log(rec.calcSurface());
```

The error I get is:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object function Shape(w,h){
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.calculateSurface = function (){
        return this.w*this.h;
    };
} has no method 'calculateSurface'
```

Answer (score 2):

This line...

```
return Shape.calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);
```

Is looking for a `calculateSurface()` method on your `Shape()` function. Except it's not there, it's on the object returned by the constructor.

You want something like this...

```
var self = this;
this.calcSurface = function(){
    return self.calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZU5Vb/).

Also, it may be worth placing `calculateSurface()` on `Shape`'s `prototype` property, that way if you create lots of `Shape` objects, you only have the method living once in memory.

Comment: @KirilNikolov Feel free to start a chat with me if you want to discuss objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
return (new Shape(this.w, this.h)).calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);
```

Comment: Will get unwieldy when there may be further methods that mutate the object.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`return Shape.calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);`

to

`return this.calculateSurface(this.w, this.h);`

Because you are pointing `Rectangle`'s Prototype to `Shape`'s in

`Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();`